# add ALL choice to combobox

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have this query that displays a form from which I can select the user.

I want to add an "ALL" choice to my combobox so that I select the data for all users instead of one user.

The sql code for this query is :

```
SELECT dbo_Users.User_Description, dbo_Movement_Details.Item_Description, 
       dbo_Movement_Details.Quantity_SU AS Requested, 
       dbo_Movement_Details.Quantity_Level3 AS Approved, dbo_Movement_Details.Stamp_Date
FROM dbo_Users 
     INNER JOIN (dbo_Movement_Details INNER JOIN dbo_Movement_Headers ON dbo_Movement_Details.Movement_Code = dbo_Movement_Headers.Movement_Code) 
     ON dbo_Users.User_Code = dbo_Movement_Headers.User_Code
WHERE (((dbo_Users.User_Description)=[Forms]![Loads & returns]![users list]) 
      AND ((dbo_Movement_Details.Stamp_Date)>=[Forms]![Loads & returns]![StartDate] 
      And (dbo_Movement_Details.Stamp_Date)<[Forms]![Loads & returns]![EndDate]) 
      AND ((dbo_Movement_Headers.Movement_Type)=4));
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: Better you add "ALL" options at the client end only, you don't need to change your query

Comment: **Five** fields in a combo box??  I've always done it with a UNION ALL statement, but I wouldn't touch that with 5 fields.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
  With Me.Combo0
    .RowSourceType = "Value List"
    .RowSource = "(All);" & .RowSource
  End With
End Sub
```

[original source](http://www.access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0043.htm)